# Checking Azure Service principal expiration using JAVA

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I am new to AZURE & I want to get the service principal's from the azure active directory using the Azure core java libraries. Any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below Java code to get the service principle's,

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal = graphClient.servicePrincipals("{id}")
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

Reference : [Get servicePrincipal - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

For workaround you can use Microsoft Graph API to get the service principle's

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
```

[image]

Comment: Yes This Graph API helped actually to fetch the SP's from azure active directory. for more info (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)